# Pie chart with only a single slice using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am trying to plot the value of fracs inside a pie chart. Inside the pie chart, I have to display the value 0. I am just getting 0, but pie chart is not visible in the output. Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fracs = [0]
plt.pie(fracs, colors = “b”, autopct=make_autopct(fracs),textprops={'fontsize' : '30', 'weight': 'bold'})
plt.title('Event Logs',fontsize = 30)

def make_autopct(values):
  def my_autopct(pct):
    total = sum(values)
    val = int(round(pct*total/100.0))
    return '{v:d}'.format(v=val)
  return my_autopct
```

Comment: What's ``make_autopct``?

Comment: @Schmuddi: Sorry provided the definition

Comment: I think the indentation of ``make_autopct`` is broken. Anyway, if that's fixed, I get the output that I expected given your code: a pie chart with one segment showing a fraction of zero, i.e. a segment with an angle of 0°. Is that not the desired output?

Comment: I fixed the indentation. No, I am trying to display a whole pie chart with number 0 written inside it.

Comment: @Schmuddi: Which basically means, i need to display a pie chart with no slices inside it and number 0 written inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you "have to display the value 0". Your code does exactly that. Your list `fracs` contains the relative contribution of the values in the list to the circumference of your pie chart. There is one value in the list, the value 0. This value contributes 0.0 to the circumference, i.e. nothing. And this is what your code produces: a slice with an angle of 0°, which appears as a single line.

In your first comment, you say that you're "trying to display a whole pie chart with number 0 written on it". This is very different from showing the value 0. A full pie chart that consists of only a single slice that fills the whole circumference can be created by passing the list `fracs = [1]` to `plt.pie()`. This shows the value 1, not 0.

But if you really, really "need to display a pie chart with no slices inside it and number 0 written inside it", as per your latest comment, this piece of code will do that for you:

```py
fracs = [1]
plt.pie(fracs, 
        autopct=lambda x: "0.0", 
        colors="b", 
        textprops={'fontsize' : '30', 'weight': 'bold'})
plt.title('Event Logs',fontsize = 30)
```

However, let me repeat: this is not a pie chart displaying the value 0. This is a pie chart showing the value 1, with the label "0.0" printed on it – even though it shows the value 1.0.

Comment: This is what I was trying to find out. Thanks.